# What is the minimum number of data points required to use ARIMA(p,d,q)?

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm using the [$\mathrm{ARIMA}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average)$(p,d,q)$ model to predict future time series data in [R](http://www.r-project.org/) (see also [R's ARIMA documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/arima.html)).

> *Q*:  What is the minimum the number of data points we must have in the time series before using $\mathrm{ARIMA}(p,d,q)$?

I originally thought it would be $\max(p,q)$, based on the model's description.  But this doesn't seem to work in R.  E.g. for the `lh` dataset, we need $4$ data points for it to work when $(p,d,q)=(1,1,1)$:

```r
 arima(lh[1:3],c(1,1,1))
Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, 
          hessian = FALSE,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
> arima(lh[1:4],c(1,1,1))

Call:
arima(x = lh[1:4], order = c(1, 1, 1))

Coefficients:
          ar1       ma1
        0.000    0.0000
s.e.  707.273  707.2718

sigma^2 estimated as 0.01333:  log likelihood = 2.22,  aic = 1.56
```

I suspect this is complicated by the method for finding the model's coefficients.

(I'm seeking the minimum number mostly for coding reasons: I want to get a feel for how good the ARIMA prediction is as (a) the number of data points vary, and (b) as p,d,q vary. So I'm plotting a lot of estimates (to see what is and what isn't meaningful). But if R returns "Error" then I need to fix it manually.)

Comment: Two things: (1) consider an AR(1) with mean 0 is y_t=$\phi_1 y_{t-1}+e_t$ - you can't fit an AR(1) to one point, you'd need 2 even with no mean and no error df - so you need more that $p$ to fit an ARIMA(p,0,0). So it *can't* be $p+q$ for an ARMA(p,q). (2) With an integrated series, you'll lose $d$ in the differencing as well, so if you're fitting a mean, and estimating $\sigma^2$ to be anything but 0, you must need - at the very least - $p+d+q+3$ observations, and even then you'd have only a single df for error. You might be able to get a fit for $p+d+q+2$ but it would be pretty meaningless.