# Minimum series length for SARIMAX based on p d q s values

Tags: time-series, python, arima

I looked at a [prior question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105952/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-data-points-required-to-use-arimap-d-q) regarding this and the comments didn't provide actionable insight. Is there any way to determine how many rows of data I'll need for `SARIMAX` forecasting if I know my (p, d, q), (P, D, Q, S) values? I get the following error:

> ValueError: maxlag should be < nobs

This error occurs given the following:

> 1W periodicity: (0, 1, 0)x(3, 0, 2, 52); dataset: 157 rows

The way I generate the p and q values is through `arma_order_select_ic` on two datasets (p,q = `make_stationary(raw_data)`; P,Q = `seasonal_decompose > seasonal.dropna()`). d and D are determined by how many times I need to `diff()` the given timeseries to make it stationary (0 for seasonal as it's already stationary by design). S is already set by the timeframe.

Given the fact that I generated these values through `arma_order_select_ic` on the data that is (in size) <= `raw_data` (due to `dropna()` in `make_stationary` and `seasonal`), why is `SARIMAX` complaining that I don't have enough data, and how can I adjust my series data to make calculations more time efficient and not fail outright given a set of p, q, d values? FWIW I don't have access to pyramid's auto-arima as I'm developing on a platform that hasn't whitelisted it. My program either crashes due to memory issues (dataset too large to process in timely manner), or `SARIMAX` fails due to there not being enough datapoints to process given the arguments. I'm searching for a way to automate ARIMA forecasting on an arbitrary dataset but it's looking more and more like that won't be feasible.